# Is there a Ubuntu in other languages (for example Russian)?

Tags: language-support, system-language

I would really like to move to Ubuntu and transfer all my gadgets (desktops, laptops, smartphones, etc.) to this wonderful operating system, but only one thing stops me - support of the Russian language, as I am not a single user of all these devices.

In my family six people, only two of them (including me) know English, respectively. The other four people have no knowledge of the English language.

Comment: It's the very idea of Ubuntu AFAIK. English-only ubuntu would be no ubuntu

Answer (score 13):

Yes, of course. For example, I use Ubuntu in Romanian. You can select this option when you will install Ubuntu.

Or, you can change the language for every user after install. Go in **System Settings** > **Language Support** and install the new language and after go in **System Settings** > **User Account**, select the user and change the language. Thus, each individual user can have his own display language.

[image]
[image]

Depending on how the thing go on [Launchpad Translations](https://translations.launchpad.net/) (and often go well), some languages can have good and almost complete translations and some of them are less good. Therefore, although Ubuntu is set up in a language other than English, it is possible that you'll be seeing some untranslated fields.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu supports a wide variety of languages, including Russian, Georgian and Ukrainian. Open the System Settings app from the Dash and select Language Support. Click on the "Install / Remove Languages" button and select the language you need. Once installed, select the language preference in each of the User accounts through the same Language Support settings for that account.